# Is VERIFY(...) a good practice in C++ coding?

Tags: c++, coding-style, verify

Also, how does it compare to throwing an exception when something goes wrong ?

Comment: Err.. what is VERIFY()? It's not in the c++ standard library... do you mean an assert statement?

Comment: It appears to be MFC-related: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcatwy09(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I wonder why the standard library has assert() but not verify()

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`VERIFY()` serves the same purpose as `ASSERT()` (or the standard library `assert()`) - to let you catch things that really *shouldn't ever™* be happening (i.e. a true code bug, something that should be fixed before release). The kinds of things that if for some reason the expression is false, there's no point to continuing because something is horribly, horribly wrong.

This is reflected in the fact that `VERIFY()` only stops the program on a false evaluation when compiling in Debug mode - in Release mode, it's transparent. The difference between `VERIFY()` and `ASSERT()` is that `VERIFY()` will still evaluate the expression in Release mode, it simply won't care about the result - whereas `ASSERT()` is completely removed from the program when compiling in Release mode and thus any side-effects of the expression within it won't take place.

Exceptions are more useful for things that *might* go wrong, but can be recovered from, since exceptions can be handled by other parts of the program.

Answer (score 10):

The question looks simple, but hides a huge subject : dealing with errors.

Summarilly I would say **assert** and **verify** are tools to use in **developement process** while **exceptions** and system calls error checking are normal parts of production code to deal with **runtime errors**.

- **Assertions** (it applies to assert and verify) are tools mostly used in defensive programming style. Their main goal is to protect against cases that should never occurs and programmer has no idea of what to do if that happen. Usually it is used to check for programming errors. When the impossible happen while debugging a program you usually want to detect and report it as fast as possible. It will simplify error correction. You can use it with some condition or even as `assert(false)` typically to check that a branch of a switch is never caught.

  I mostly use assertions when dealing with third-party code whose behavior I'm unsure. For checking behavior of my own code code under development I usually prefer unit testing.

  Now, as Schroëdinger taught us, mesures change things. You may sometime have code that works in debug mode when assert is enabled and stop working in release mode. It usually is the symptom of an hidden bug inside the assertion condition (side effect, time sensitive code). Verify minimize this kind of risk, but it can be considered a bad practice, like sweeping dust behind the carpet.

  You can also use **verify** for fast coding as scafolding for places where you didn't set up a real error handling yet. I do not believe you should let any verify in production code.

- **Exceptions** are a normal part of program control flow. Most often they are used to deal with errors, but it's not their only possible use (those who use other languages like python will know what I'm speaking about). Neither should they be considered as the only error management tool. When not wrapped in a c++ aware library, system calls still return an error code instead of raising an Exception.

  As a rule of thumb Exceptions should be caught by the nearest object that is able to handle them sensibly.

  Also not all exceptions should be considered as fatal errors and stop program. Imagine you are dealing with a network video streaming library returning error cases through exceptions. It the library throw an Exception warning that a frame was dropped, you usually don't want to stop the program but just get it ready for the next frame.

  Even when the best thing to do is to stop the program you should not let exception do it for you (and you have even less reason to use assert for that purpose in production code). There should always exist a top level exception handler for that purpose that makes explicit calls to exit() of like. Not doing it merely show that the programmer didn't care about what may happen and probably didn't thought about it.

Comment: Putting in a top-level exception handler for 'uncaught exceptions' has the drawback that when an uncaught exception occurs, the stack is destroyed up to the top-level handler; which will then do something completely uninteresting like say which exception has occurred, then as you say, exit the program anyway.  Leaving it un-handled entirely gives the debugger the opportunity to stop the program at the std::terminate with the entire execution stack available and inspectable.

Answer (score 7):

In Visual C++, there are two macros for checking conditions: `ASSERT` and `VERIFY`.

In debug mode, they both behave the same: that is, they both evaluate their argunment and if the result is 0, they both halt the program with an assertion failure dialog box.

The difference lies in release mode. In release, mode, `ASSERT` is completely removed from the program: it doesn't evaluate it's expression at all. `VERIFY`, on the other hand, still evaluates the expression, it just ignores the result.

**Personally**, my opinion is that if the check is valuable in debug mode then it's still valuable in release mode as well and you probably shouldn't use either of them. Just do the test and throw an exception (or use a custom macro that expands to `assert()` in debug mode and an exception in release mode).

Comment: One useful difference is if you have "nitpicky" tests that take a while to run, you can put them in an `ASSERT()` and then not worry about performance losses in Release mode.

Comment: You opion about debug mode checks being in release mode is well supported here too!